# Why has Google Chrome lost all of my saved passwords?

Tags: windows-vista, google-chrome, passwords

I have a Dell laptop running Windows Vista. A few days ago I had a problem with Google Chrome saying "Your profile could not be opened correctly. Some features may be unavailable."
I believe that the error is caused by a sad attempt to create another User profile.
Anyway, I want to be able to retrieve all of my passwords and get rid of that error.

Could anyone help me?

Comment: You could try what's stated here:
http://securityxploded.com/chromepassworddecryptor.php

Answer (score 10):

i hope the following link will help you to fix the problem

https://productforums.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/chrome/xRYwUu45ycs

> 1. Check your "Google Dashboard" (see link at top of Chrome Settings page) and verify that your synced passwords are really gone (in the
>      "Chrome Sync" section you should see a line for "Passwords:". the
>      number is probably very low (or maybe zero))
> 2. Restore the sync data files mentioned above (restore to some other, temporary location than where it normally lives)
> 3. Quit Chrome (and then wait a few seconds to make sure it's really dead)
> 4. Copy the restored data files into place (see file path above for Mac or maybe someone will reply with Windows info)
> 5. VERY IMPORTANT: Turn off WiFi and/or disconnect from the Internet (you need to make sure Chrome cannot talk to Google's servers for a
>      little while)
> 6. Start Chrome
> 7. Insure that your previously lost passwords have come back to life (look in Settings -> Manage saved passwords) They may take a few
>      seconds to appear.
> 8. Once you've seen that all your passwords have returned, tell chrome to not sync passwords (Under "Settings -> Advanced sync settings..."
>      uncheck "Passwords")
> 9. Quit and restart Chrome again
> 10. Insure all your passwords are still there
> 11. Turn on Wifi and/or reconnect to the network (so chrome can talk to google again)
> 12. Restart chrome again
> 13. Re-enable password sync (back to "Settings -> Advanced sync settings..." check the box for "Passwords")
> 14. Restart chrome one more time (why not? It don't hurt nothin')
> 15. Wait about 60 seconds or so then check your "Google Dashboard" and verify that the number of stored passwords is now at a more acceptable
>       number (mine went from 3 to 214 to prove that I'd fixed it)

Comment: In general, when you write an answer, please don't only post a link, post an actually usable solution. Links can die with time, so it would be better to have the actual solution written here, for later.

Comment: i try to correct myself thank you for the valuable comments

Answer (score 3):

If you have ever logged in to your Google account in Chrome on another computer you can restore the passwords that have been cached on that other computer via the steps below.

*Note that this is only a viable solution if you have signed in to Chrome recently on another computer with the same account *and* synced your data to that computer.

1. Go to `chrome://flags` on the other computer with cached passwords
2. Change the selection for **Password import and export** from `Default` to `Enabled`
3. Go to `chrome://settings/passwords` and click the newly visible **Export** button to download a plaintext CSV file containing your passwords
4. Repeat the above steps in your browser without passwords, instead clicking the **Import** button in Step 3

---

Source: http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-backup-saved-passwords-in-google-chrome-browser/

Comment: I am on Version 94.0.4606.61 (Official Build) (x86_64) on Mac and there is no "Password import and export". I only see "Password import"

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by bugs, introduced by brilliant Google developers. You can recover your password for individual site this way:

[image]

then you will be prompted to input your google password and after that you can lookup your password:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I closed my Chrome, disconnected from my wi-fi, reconnected to my wi-fi and opened Chrome and everything was back to normal. I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you sync your local data to a Google Account, try turning sync off and deleting all local data, then turning sync on again. You can turn sync off and delete local data via the "Turn off" button at chrome://settings/syncSetup (or just search for `sync` in the Settings page).

[image: First click the "Turn off" button to summon the "Turn off sync and personalisation" modal. Then check the "Clear bookmarks, history, passwords and more from this device" checkbox in the modal. Finally, click the "Turn off" button in the modal.]

(Background: I use Chrome on Ubuntu with sync enabled, and twice my passwords have vanished. The behaviour I see when this happens is that all passwords vanish from chrome://settings/passwords and passwords are no longer autofilled, but that if I go to https://passwords.google.com/ I can still see my passwords - i.e. they disappear locally but are still stored in my Google Account. The first time this happened to me, I fixed it by uninstalling Chrome, hunting down and scrubbing all local data stored by Chrome, and reinstalling Chrome. The most recent time it happened to me - today - I tried the approach I describe above: just turning off sync and checking the box to clear local data, then re-enabling sync. This worked, and is less annoying than reinstalling Chrome, so it's what I'd recommend you try as well.)

Answer (score 0):

This is an ongoing problem. Chrome gets upgraded and zap - all saved passwords disappear. The only way to retrieve them is by logging into one's Google Account and manually retrieving them.